# Is there a a way to overload 'is' operator?

Tags: json, dart, operators, overloading

I designed a class which wrap an internal json object.
My class acts like a real json, returning a Map or a List depending of the current intermediate node (a json is made of Maps, Lists and values).
This class overrides *runtimeType* to use it's current json type :

```
  @override   
  get runtimeType{   
    return (_json.runtimeType);  
  }
```

This indeed overrides the type to an *_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>* which is what the json uses for a Map or to an *List<dynamic>* for a List.
But this is not enough to override tests like **(result is Map)**  or **(result is List)** which works for json but not for my class.

I try to overload operator `is` but i don't find how to.
is there a  way to do that ?

Comment: There is no overloading in dart.

Comment: You can mixin `ListMixin<E>` and `MapMixin<K, V>` so you type is actually a List or Map. By doing so, the `is` operator will work as your expect. Also, your override of runtimeType is not something you should do since it makes debugging a lot harder.

Comment: @julemand101 good indication.   I do an ancestor MapList with two subclasses:    class MapListMap extends MapList with MapMixin    and  class MapListList extends MapList with ListMixin  and it's ok.    thanks.